# Understanding different ways of export in Brunch config

Tags: javascript, module, brunch

So i got this config file:

```
exports.files = {
  javascripts: {
    joinTo: {
      'vendor.js': /^(?!app)/, // Files that are not in `app` dir.
      'app.js': /^app/
    }
  },
  stylesheets: {joinTo: 'app.css'}
};

exports.plugins = {
  babel: {presets: ['latest']}
};

exports.npm = {
  styles: {
    bootstrap: ['dist/css/bootstrap.css']
  }
}
```

When the above code is triggered the 5 files are built and compiled into 3, as expected.

Then for the sake of better understanding, I change the **first export** in my config file to this:

```
module.exports = {
    files: {
        javascripts: {
            joinTo: {
                'vendor.js': /^(?!app)/, 
                'app.js': /^app/
            }
        },
        stylesheets: {joinTo: 'app.css'}
    }
}

exports.plugins = {
  babel: {presets: ['latest']}
};

exports.npm = {
  styles: {
    bootstrap: ['dist/css/bootstrap.css']
  }
}
```

And now the bootstrap code doesn't get compiled into the final stylesheets. Why am I experiencing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not directly related to Brunch but more how node handles exports. Check out this explanation taken from the [node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut):

> The exports variable is available within a module's file-level scope,
>   and is assigned the value of module.exports before the module is
>   evaluated.
>
> It allows a shortcut so that `module.exports.f = ...` can be written
>   more succinctly as `exports.f = ...` However, be aware that like any
>   variable, if a new value is assigned to `exports`, it is no longer bound
>   to `module.exports`:

```
module.exports.hello = true; // Exported from require of module
exports = { hello: false };  // Not exported, only available in the module
```